# Apollo Rx Query With Single

Tags: android, graphql, apollo-android

Apollo Android Client [support RxJava2](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/advanced/rxjava2/). They support

1. Observable< Response< T> >
2. Single
3. Completable

From official doc

```
val query = EpisodeHeroNameQuery(episode = Episode.EMPIRE.toInput())
val observable = apolloClient.rxQuery(query)
```

`apolloClient.rxQuery` returns a `Observable`, But I want to use `Single` here. How can i use `Single` here

Comment: My question is not about to convert observable to single.I know i can convert observable yo single but I want to know  how can i directly use Single in graphql query.

Comment: I have solved this using `Observable.singleOrError()` , Hope it may help someone